# List Validations

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, modern-experience, validation

I am terrible at writing formulas. I need a list validation formula to make all fields mandatory unless the status is in DRAFT.

```
=NOT([Stage]=0 DRAFT,IF([Function]="",FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

But there are about 20 more fields to add to this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using formula in below format:

```
=IF([Stage] = "DRAFT", TRUE, IF(OR(ISBLANK([Column1]), ISBLANK([Column2]), ISBLANK([Column3]), ISBLANK([Column4]), ISBLANK([Column5])), FALSE, TRUE))
```

You can add up to 30 conditions/columns inside `OR` function. For more information about functions used & it's syntax, check below documentation:

[Examples of common formulas in lists](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/examples-of-common-formulas-in-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)

Comment: Hi, does this answer your question?